# How to print the name of current row when using apply in R?

Tags: r, statistics

For example, I have a matrix `k`

```
> k
  d e
a 1 3
b 2 4
```

I want to apply a function on k

```
> apply(k,MARGIN=1,function(p) {p+1})
a b
d 2 3
e 4 5
```

However, I also want to print the `rowname` of the row being `apply` so that I can know which row the function is applied on at that time.

It may looks like this:

```
apply(k,MARGIN=1,function(p) {print(rowname(p)); p+1})
```

But I really don't do how to do that in R.
Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: Can you clarify what answer you're expecting? If you add 1 to every number in the 1st instance of `k`, you don't get the answer in your 2nd instance of `k`.

Comment: There's lots of really messy suggestions here - can you let me know if my proposed solution does what you're seeking?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot do that with `apply`, but you could loop through the `rownames` of your data frame. Lame example:

```
lapply(rownames(mtcars), function(x) sprintf('The mpg of %s is %s.', x, mtcars[x, 1]))
```

Comment: You can do it with `apply` - and not only is looping a really bad idea in general, but the above example doesn't actually print them one by one (put in a Sys.sleep() delay and you'll see they all come out in one burst at the end)...

Comment: @TimP - `flush.console()` is handy fo rthings like this

Comment: As @TimP demonstrates in his answer, this is possible with `apply()`. This accepted answer is misleading.

Comment: @Berkan - of course there are work-arounds, it would be e.g. a lot simpler to add the `rownames` as a new variable to the `data.frame` and `apply` a function on the top of that instead of adding some mysterious index. What I've written above: `apply` would ditch all `attributes` of rows/columns, and for such tasks (without extending the existing `data.frame`) this answer *might* be the quickest (not in the means of CPU performance) solution.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a neat solution to what I think you're asking. (I've called the input matrix `mat` rather than `k` for clarity - in this example, `mat` has 2 columns and 10 rows, and the rows are named abc1 through to abc10.)

In the code below, the result `out1` is the thing you wanted to calculate (the outcome of the apply command). The result `out2` comes out identically to `out1` except that it prints out the rownames that it is working on (I put in a delay of 0.3 seconds per row so you can see it really does do this - take this out when you want the code to run full speed obviously!)

The trick I came up with was to cbind the row numbers (1 to n) onto the left of `mat` (to create a matrix with one additional column), and then use this to refer back to the rownames of `mat`. Note the line `x = y[-1]` which means that the actual calculation within the function (here, adding 1) ignores the first column of row numbers, which means it's the same as the calculation done for `out1`. Whatever sort of calculation you want to perform on the rows can be done this way - just pretend that `y` never existed, and formulate your desired calculation using `x`. Hope this helps.

```
set.seed(1234)
mat = as.matrix(data.frame(x = rpois(10,4), y = rpois(10,4)))
rownames(mat) = paste("abc", 1:nrow(mat), sep="")
out1 = apply(mat,1,function(x) {x+1})
out2 = apply(cbind(seq_len(nrow(mat)),mat),1,
             function(y) {
                           x = y[-1]
                           cat("Doing row:",rownames(mat)[y[1]],"\n")
                           Sys.sleep(0.3)
                           x+1
                          }
            )

identical(out1,out2)
```

Comment: The accepted answer is false and misleading. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a variable outside of the apply call to keep track of the row index and pass the row names as an extra argument to your function:

```
idx <- 1
apply(k, 1, function(p, rn) {print(rn[idx]); idx <<- idx + 1; p + 1}, rownames(k))
```

Comment: It works! But it still needs to use a global variable as a counter.. not very elegant..

Comment: It's easy if you're allowed to use global variables, but my solution above doesn't require these (assuming I've understood the task correctly) :)

Comment: This is no different than using a looping variable in a for loop, really. It is no less elegant than that.

Comment: Because my input was a subset of a larger dataset, `rownames` did not produce sequential integers.  Therefore, I replaced `rownames(k)` with `1:nrow(k)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The `cat()` function is what you want to use when printing results during evaluation of a function. `paste()`, conversely, just returns a character vector but doesn't send it to the command window.

The solution below uses a counter created as a closure, allowing it to "remember" how many times the function has been run before. Note the use of the global assign `<<-`. If you really want to understand what's going on here, I recommend reading through this wiki https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/

Note there may be an easier way to do this; my solution assumes that there is no way to access the rownumber or rowname of a current row using typical means within an apply function. As previously mentioned, this would be no problem in a loop.

```
k <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4),ncol=2)
rownames(k) <- c("a","b")
colnames(k) <- c("d","e")


make.counter <- function(x){
    i <- 0
    function(){
        i <<- i+1
        i   
    }
}

counter1 <- make.counter()

apply(k,MARGIN=1,function(p){
    current.row <- rownames(k)[counter1()]
    cat(current.row,"\n")
    return(p+1)
})
```