# R: rownames, colnames, dimnames and names in apply

Tags: r, function, radix, apply

I would like to use apply to run across the rows of a matrix, and I would like to use the rowname of the current row in my function. It seems you can't use `rownames`, `colnames`, `dimnames` or `names` directly inside the function. I am aware that I can probably create a workaround based on information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10956873/1478381).

But my question is how does `apply` handle row and column names of the array in it's first argument, and the assignment of names to objects created inside the function called by `apply`? It seems a bit inconsistent, as I hope to show by the following example. Is there a reason why it was designed like this?

```
# Toy data
m <- matrix( runif(9) , nrow = 3 )
rownames(m) <- LETTERS[1:3]
colnames(m) <- letters[1:3]
m
          a         b           c
A 0.5092062 0.3786139 0.120436569
B 0.7563015 0.7127949 0.003358308
C 0.8794197 0.3059068 0.985197273

# These return NULL
apply( m , 1 , FUN = function(x){ rownames(x) } )
NULL
apply( m , 1 , FUN = function(x){ colnames(x) } )
NULL
apply( m , 1 , FUN = function(x){ dimnames(x) } )
NULL

# But...
apply( m , 1 , FUN = function(x){ names(x) } )
     A   B   C  
[1,] "a" "a" "a"
[2,] "b" "b" "b"
[3,] "c" "c" "c"
# This looks like a column-wise matrix of colnames, with the rownames of m as the column names to me

# And further you can get...
n <- apply( m , 1 , FUN = function(x){ names(x) } )
dimnames(n)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"

# But you can't do...
apply( m , 1 , FUN = function(x){ n <- names(x); dimnames(n) } )
NULL
```

I just want to understand what happens internally in apply? Many thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think your confusion stems from the fact that `apply` does not pass an array (or matrix) to the function specified in `FUN`.

It passes each row of the matrix in turn. Each row is itself "only" a (named) vector:

```
> m[1,]
         a          b          c 
0.48768161 0.61447934 0.08718875
```

So your function has only this named vector to work with.

For your middle example, as documented in `apply`:

> If each call to FUN returns a vector of length n, then apply returns
>   an array of dimension c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN]) if n > 1. If n equals 1,
>   apply returns a vector if MARGIN has length 1 and an array of
>   dimension dim(X)[MARGIN] otherwise.

So `function(x) names(x)` returns a vector of length 3 for each row, so the final result is the matrix you see. But that matrix is being constructed at the end of the `apply` function, on the results of `FUN` being applied to each row individually.