# Why do matrix column and row dimensions switch when using apply?

Tags: r

**Apparently this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521260/why-apply-returns-a-transposed-xts-matrix), thanks for the quick answer!**

The following issue has been puzzling me lately and I hope someone can help me with this. When using apply, the dimensions of my matrix end up being switched. See example below:

```
> A = matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), nrow=2, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    4    3
[2,]    1    5    7

> M = c(1, 2, 3)

> B = apply(A, 1, "*", M)
> B
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    8   10
[3,]    9   21
```

I know this can easily be transposed, so that isn't the problem. But my question is, why does R do this?

Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: We can just do `A*M[col(A)]` without the `apply`

Comment: See also [Results transposed with R apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312389/results-transposed-with-r-apply/18312548#18312548) or [R: rownames, colnames, dimnames and names in apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229199/r-rownames-colnames-dimnames-and-names-in-apply).

Answer (score 1):

The elements of a matrix are stored in RAM: 1. elements of the first column, 2. elements of the second column, ... and so on. So, when `apply()` builds the resulting object the first elements are the elements of the first column ... and so on.
(In memory the position of the elements of a matrix is FORTRAN-like.)