# R: Accessing and using names of data.frames within a list during an `apply` function

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function that takes a list of data.frames (`somelist`) and writes them out to .csv files, each named the same as the data.frame being written (i.e., `a1.csv`, `a2.csv`, `a3.csv`).

```
somelist <- list(a1 = data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3),
                 a2 = data.frame(d = 4, e = 5, f = 6),
                 a3 = data.frame(g = 7, h = 8, i = 9))

csvout <- function (y) {
    z <- deparse(substitute(y))
    write.table(y, file = paste0("~/somefolder/",
                                 z,
                                 ".csv"),
                sep = ",",
                row.names = FALSE)
    print(z)
}

sapply(somelist, csvout)
```

That is the closest I get, and instead, the files are named what is printed for `z`:

```
[1] "X[[1L]]"
[1] "X[[2L]]"
[1] "X[[3L]]"
       a1        a2        a3 
"X[[1L]]" "X[[2L]]" "X[[3L]]"
```

In searching the documentation for an answer, I think I'm on the right track here in `?sapply`, but I've been unable to connect the dots:

> For historical reasons, the calls created by lapply are unevaluated,
>   and code has been written (e.g., bquote) that relies on this. This
>   means that the recorded call is always of the form FUN(X[[i]], ...),
>   with i replaced by the current (integer or double) index

**Update**

I can use a `for` loop using syntax similar to `C` programming...

```
for (i in 1:length(somelist)) {
    write.table(i, file = paste0("~/somefolder/",
                                 names(somelist)[i],
                                 ".csv"),
                sep = ",",
                row.names = FALSE)
}
```

But I'm trying to code more natively in `R` and I'm aware that the `apply` family, or at least using a vectorized `for` loop (i.e., `for (all in somelist) {` instead of `for (i in 1:length(somelist)) {`) is preferable for efficiency and proper coding etiquette.

Comment: You FOR-loop solution is missing "somelist[i]" in the second line.

Comment: It worked for me. In this instance, I removed the extra function `csvout` and just piped the data.frames in to the `write.table` function directly.

Comment: Sorry, actually you're right. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really, really, really dirty, but I think it works as you described. Of course for more than nine data.frames it needs adjustment in the substitutes part.

```
csvout <- function (y, csvnames) {
  write.table(y, file = paste0("test",
                                   csvnames[as.numeric(substr(deparse(substitute(y)),4,4))],
                               ".csv"),
              sep = ",",
              row.names = FALSE)
}

sapply(somelist, FUN=csvout, names(somelist))
```

I suppose you know that, but if you implemented a FOR-loop instead of sapply this would be much easier because you could directly reference the data.frame names with the names function.

Edit:
This is the FOR-loop solution which works no matter how many data.frames you've got:

```
csvout <- function (y) {
  for (i in 1:length(y)){
    write.table(y[i], file = paste0("test",
                                 names(y)[i],
                                 ".csv"),
                sep = ",",
                row.names = FALSE)  
  }  
}

csvout(somelist)
```

Comment: Thanks @Juergen, can you append your answer with the `for` loop alternative?

Comment: Added it. Although I see you already found the solution. I'm not aware of something like "for all in something" / For-each-loop in R. Usually you make use of (s/l)apply. The only drawback known to me is the problematic you described regarding the names. For more information on workarounds see this thread and especially this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10959033/4166885. In your case, you could add another attribute to the data.frame, e.g. rowIndex. I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` in similar fashion like `apply(1:length,function(i){})`

Comment: Thanks for this -- was unaware of this functionality. I've got a small-ish list of data.frames to write, so efficiency is not a big issue, but are you familiar with the relative efficiencies of using `for (i in length:x) {}` vs `apply(1:length, function(i) {})` when performing lots of calculations, or memory-intensive calculations?

Comment: I was hoping someone would chime in since I'm only speculating, but as I see it the only difference is `apply ` is deferred and `for ` is forced. So apply will only calculate the fields actually used and for will calculate all